# Как в tinyMCE вставить текст извне?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

На странице имеется текстовое поле редактора tinyMCE и кнопка вне его. Требуется, чтобы по нажатию кнопки в текстовое поле, причём в текущую позицию, вставлялся какой либо текст.
Я нашёл как сделать похоже, но не совсем то:

```
// Обработчик нажатия кнопки

// getContent сохраняет html активного редактора

// setContent вставляет какой либо html в редактор

old_html=tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent( old_html+"Привет");
```

Таким образом я могу вставить html - код в начало или конец редактора, а надо внутрь. Так ине смог найти нужную функцию, может кто знает?

Comment: @Александр Егоров, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте следующую команду:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'Текст для вставки');
```

Вот пример:  http://jsfiddle.net/6jLcv/

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно